# How to safely open-source a Windows Store app Visual Studio project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, open-source, windows-store

I have a Windows Store app (http://lanscan.rcook.org/) that I am contemplating making open source so that the community can contribute to it and/or learn from my experience. I have realized after scanning through the source code that there are various parts of the repository that would be inappropriate to publish via GitHub or other open-source hosting services. At the very least, code-signing artifacts such as `.pfx` files would need to be stripped out as these would allow malicious individuals to publish new versions of the app to the Windows Store under my account by masquerading as me.

Does anybody have a definitive list of what files within a Windows Store app's Visual Studio solution are not safe to make public in this way? Are there parts of the `.sln` or `.csproj` files I should strip out of the project? As with any private information, this would all need to be removed from the repository and its history.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The recent version of `.gitignore` for Visual Studio projects can be found here:

https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/VisualStudio.gitignore

It contains filenames like `*.pfx` etc. Also make sure that there is no Certificate Password set in .csrpoj

Comment: Thanks. I am already familiar with this file and using a variant of it in my project. Is there content _within_ files themselves which should not be included? I'm thinking mainly of `.csproj` files which can contain various Windows Store account bindings used for publishing apps and which might reveal sensitive information.

Comment: My main concerns are over the `PackageCertificateThumbprint` element in my `.csproj` file and the `Package.StoreAssociation.xml` and `Package.appxmanifest` files. I don't think that the thumbprint is sensitive information, but I would like to double-check.